# Empty request body causing a 500 error when using [FromBody]

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Hi We have an action method that reads from the request body, which is declared like this:

```
[BondControllerConfig]
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> LookupByUserId(string userId, [FromBody] IdBody idBody){
    ...
    }
}

public class IdBody
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

It works fine except when the request body is empty - we get a 500 error:
*Unsupported Media Type The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header. The inferred media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported for this resource. No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'IdBody' from content with media type 'application/octet-stream'.*

We think that if the request body is empty and the Content-Type is missing, it defaults to 'application/octet-stream' Media type. The proposed solution is to update the BondControllerConfigAttribute class to register a media type handler for 'application/octet-stream' - since the body is empty anyway, the implementation of this media type handler can be real simple. For the large part, this seems to work. But it seems hacky, and I was wondering if there's another approach to this problem. Someone suggested that we remove [FromBody] IdBody idBody from the action method, and just read the Request.Content directly to determine whether the request body is empty. But wasn't sure if changing the action signature is the right way to go about, or the consequence of it. Is there another approach that I've missed?

Comment: Have you considered to declare IdBody as nullable field? 
If you received and empty body, idBody will be null. 
[FromBody] IdBody? idBody